# Memory Overflow due to not deleted Objects

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, out-of-memory

I am using a static method in C# to solve a numerical problem. I do this several times during the runtime of my program. After a while, the program crashes, due to a memory overflow. I think, there is something left in the main memory every time I call the static method. I think it is the Dictionary object, which I use like this:

```
public static Solution solve(Problem p)
{
  Dictionary<String, List<int>> tours = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
  /*do stuff*/
  List<int>[] toursarray = new List<int>[tours.Count];
  int counter = 0;
  foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<int>> kvp in tours)
  {
    toursarray[counter] = kvp.Value;
    counter++;
  }
  tours.Clear();
  tours = null;
  /*do stuff*/
  for (int t = 0; t < toursarray.Length; t++)
    toursarray[t] = null;
}
```

Is there any debugging tool, which I can use to verify if there are `List<int>` objects left in the memory? I am using Visual Studio Community. Also, what can I do to avoid "hidden objects" in the memory?

Comment: The advice to simply add a Dispose method is completely wrong. If you have disposable resources you would have to release them, just having a Dispose method is not magic.

Comment: What are you doing in this function? It does not make any sense. The  parameter `Problem p` is not used. A dictionary is created and which was never populated before using it.

Comment: I agree with MKR; the code you showed doesn't seem to be causing the leak. Most likely it's due to a static list, or a to big of an array. Which could be in the /* do stuff */ part.

Comment: May be `toursarray.Clear(); toursarray = null` can make difference. But potential memory leak seems somewhere else.

Comment: @Crowcoder : The dispose will release all object in the class.  It will not release the child object unless the children have a dispose method.  In this case the dictionary will get disposed.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Actually, you were right and this was not the crucial part of the code. I loaded a numeric optimization framework, which needs to be disposed of after each optimization. Otherwise, the data stays in memory. This was the problem... Thanks for your time!

Comment: @jdweng I'm sorry, but that is wrong. A Dictionary is not disposable and the Dispose method itself does nothing, you have to implement the code to dispose things, and only things that hold unmanaged resources qualify.

Comment: A dictionary will dispose, but it will not dispose the value IF it the value linked to another object.  And you do not want to delete the value if it is linked.

Comment: @jdweng A Dictionary does not implement IDisposable so it cannot dispose.